# Calling AcquireCredentialsHandle after ImpersonateSecurityContext returns no credentials

Tags: kerberos, sspi, kerberos-delegation

I am writing a server supporting Kerberos which needs to accept delegated credentials from a client, impersonate that client, and perform another kerberos conversation with a remote server acting as the client.

Currently, the server completes the negotiation with the client using AcceptSecurityContext. After calling QuerySecurityContext for the flags, they indicate both ASC_RET_DELEGATE and ASC_RET_MUTUAL_AUTH. Then I call ImpersonateSecurityContext which succeeds (SEC_E_OK).

At this point, I'm a little unclear on what to do. To act as a client, I would assume that I should call AcquireCredentialsHandle without a SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY struct to get the default credentials for the current "thread", which should be those that I've just impersonated. However, this call always returns SEC_E_NO_CREDENTIALS.

I can't seem to find any code samples out there doing this and running through delegation/impersonation checklists all yield that the "boxes" are checked in Active Directory correctly.

What am I supposed to be doing instead or what am I doing wrong? I can provide more information as requested, just unsure of what that would be.

Comment: You might not be doing anything wrong code-wise.  Can we take a peek at what you've got checked on the Delegation tab of the computer account on which your server process is running in Active Directory?